# Telescopic cascode operational amplifier: why not rail the bias nodes?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cascode

In a fully differential telescopic cascode opamp, there is a bias voltage for two of the nMOSFETs whose gates are tied together and a bias voltage for two of the pMOSFETs whose gates are tied together. Why wouldn't the nMOSFETs' gates be tied to Vdd and the pMOSFETs' gates tied to ground?

Edit: Sorry for being vague, folks, I was posting this question from my phone last night so a) I didn't have the schematic I wanted, and b) I was tired and left out a critical detail: yes, telescopic *cascode* op-amp is what I'm referencing. Specifically, I'm talking about the Vbn and Vbp nodes from the figure below.

[image: Two versions of the telescopic cascode operational amplifier referenced in the question.]

Comment: I'm unsure what a telescopic op-amp is. Maybe add a link?

Comment: What circuit exactly are you looking at?

Comment: Voted as an unclear question as there is no schematic to discuss. Also "telescopic opamp" means nothing to me even though I have over 25 years of experience with opamp circuits.

Comment: Because the 4 FETs would operate in TRIODE.

Comment: That's a name that has fallen into disuse. It is just a cascoded differential pair, which has biasing issues particularly with the more common power rails. A folded cascode has the same advantages with a much wider signal range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the 4 FETs would operate in TRIODE.

The output voltage-gain would be very low.

The output voltages would be constantly fighting the FET pair with lowest Rtriode.

Comment: I think I get it. I'm going through a design exercise for a telescopic cascode opamp, but I have no idea how to optimize for those two bias voltages. I ran a primary and secondary voltage sweep on those two points, sweeping them both from Vss and Vdd, and I was using the current of M11 to try to figure out where those nodes need to be to bias the circuit. The current was the highest when Vbn was at Vdd and Vbp was at ground, but that's because Vgs begins dominating both the triode current and saturation current when Von gets big enough. Am I more or less getting the picture?

Comment: I think you are correct.